# Minimization of path lengths between points in interior and "slots" on boundary

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, optimization, algorithms, euclidean-geometry

#### The problem

Consider a map (such as a physical map of a country, not a mathematical mapping) which has some points marked on it, for example by placing pins on the map.
The map may then be modeled mathematically as a rectangle in the plane and some set of points in the interior of the rectangle.

Each of these points has at least one associated sheet of information (again, a physical sheet with printed information), but may have more. Each sheet of information is unique, and two points on the interior of the rectangle may not be associated with the same sheet.
These sheets are to be placed around the edge of the map (the rectangle) in any order and connected to their corresponding point by a straight line. Each sheet has the same size, and each sheet must not overlap any other sheet.
To make the model simpler, each sheet could be thought of as a single point occupying some "slot" on the boundary of the rectangle. That is, the boundary of the rectangle should be divided into $n$ sections of equal length, where $n$ is the total number of sheets, and each section should contain at most one sheet.

My problem is then the following: each point in the interior of the rectangle should be connected to the corresponding "slot" on the boundary of the rectangle so that each path is as short as possible. The sheets may be freely moved between the "slots" to facilitate this (keeping in mind that two sheets may not occupy the same slot), but the points in the interior of the rectangle may not be moved.

#### My background

I have not studied graph theory or computer science, so this may be a completely solved problem. If it is, I would very much like a recommendation of literature on the subject. I have however run this problem by a friend writing his thesis on mathematical modeling for machine learning, and he could not think of any "obvious" solutions.

I do have an understanding of linear algebra and multivariable calculus and I have some experience with programming.

#### What I have thought of

An obvious solution to this problem for small data sets is to simply try all possible solutions. Since each sheet can only occupy one position at a time, there are $n!$ permutations of sheets, which is feasibly brute forced for small values of $n$.

However, I would like a more "mathematical" solution, which would preferably also be more efficient.

It would most likely also be possible to use some kind of genetic algorithm to determine a solution that is "good enough". However, such an algorithm would need to optimize $n$ path lengths at once, which may make it hard to create a fitness function that does not lead to edge cases where one path is allowed to be very long to make many other paths slightly shorter. Ideally, all paths would have similar lengths, assuming that the map is not much taller than it is wide or vice versa.

I can not think of any way to solve this problem that does not either calculate all permutations of sheets or does not guarantee an optimal solution.

**In essence my question is if there is any established body of work regarding this type of problem, or if there is a better/different way of thinking about the problem that might make it easier to reason about or model it.**

#### Edit: A physical example

Think of a map of an amusement park where some points of interest are marked. Around the map, printed sheets of paper with detailed descriptions of each point are placed so that they do not overlap. These descriptions are the "sheets" in the above description.
The problem is then how to place these sheets so that the lines connecting the points of interest marked on the map and the sheets of paper are as short as possible.

Comment: I don't really understand the problem. You have a rectangle of given size with some given points marked on it, that much I get. What is a "sheet" -- is it a given point on the boundary? a movable point on the boundary? a movable *segment* of the boundary? What is a slot -- is it the same as a sheet? or does a sheet fit inside a slot? or vice versa? If you could add an example figure to illustrate, it would help a lot.

Comment: A slot is some segment of the boundary of the rectangle. It can not be moved, but each slot can hold a single (or no) sheet.
In the "real world", a sheet would be a physical sheet of paper, which could be placed anywhere along the boundary of the map so long as the sheets do not overlap (so that the information on the sheet can be read).
To make the model simpler, each sheet is instead confined to a slot, so as to discretize the positions of the sheets.

Comment: So as far as I can tell, you have a fixed set of points and a fixed set of slots, and you want to match points to slots so that the total distance is minimized. If so, this is the [assignment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem) and there are many polynomial-time algorithms for it.

Comment: I think you're right, but I do not think that this is a linear assignment problem, which, as far as I can read from your linked article and a quick google search, means that it does not generally have a polynomial-time solution.
The reason I do not think this is a linear problem is that minimizing the sum of the individual path lengths is not sufficient since it may lead to some paths being very long in exchange for most paths being shorter. As discussed in the question, I would like the cost function to factor in the preference for many slightly longer paths instead of one long path somehow.

Comment: You can minimize the sum of *squared* distances if you want to penalize especially long paths. In fact, you can minimize the sum of the $p$th power of distances for any $p$ between $1$ and $\infty$. When $p$ is very large, this approximates minimizing the *maximum* length.

Comment: Thank you, this makes perfect sense. I guess I will have to do some trial and error regarding the size of $p$ to obtain an acceptable compromise between minimizing total and maximum length.
If you would summarize your comments as an answer I would be very happy to accept it.